How to customize "From" name for SNS emails
Can the "From" name be customized when sending emails using Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS)? If so, what steps or configurations are required to set a custom "From" name for email notifications sent via SNS?
When I send emails using Amazon SNS, the received emails display "AWS Notifications" as the sender. How can I change this to display a custom name or domain instead?

Amazon SNS does not provide a direct way to customise the "From" name for email notifications. SNS is primarily designed for sending notifications, not for customising email sender details. At least I cannot find any hint in the docs[1].
However, if you need to send emails with a custom "From" name, you can use Amazon Simple Email Service (SES) in conjunction with SNS.
[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-email-notifications.html
